# How to change tile size in pixels on a fixed zoom map?

Tags: javascript, size, zooming, openlayers, tile

I'm using OpenLayers to render a custom map of a virtual world (not Earth) with a fixed zoom (zoom=8). I've checked the rendered canvas and each tile is 256 pixels squared. I wanted to change the tile size to something smaller (like 16px), and I couldn't find how to do it anywhere.

What I'm doing:

```
var zoom = 8;
var side = 800
var extent = [0, 0, zoom*side*2, zoom*side*2];
var center = [zoom*side+400/8/2, zoom*side-400/8/2];

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'decentraland-images',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: extent,
});
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileImage({
      url: 'map/{z},{x},{y}.png',
      wrapX: false,
    }),
  }), 
],
view: new ol.View({
    projection: projection,
    center: center, //ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
    zoom: zoom,
    minZoom: zoom,
    maxZoom: zoom,
  })
});
```

Here's my current full code in case you want to look: https://pastebin.com/TCHCBh5c.
Here's a deployed version: https://maraoz.com/decentraland-maps/

Answer (score 2):

You should set a up tilegrid which reflects the data you are using.  It seems you have 784 x 783 pixels tiles available only where z = 5.  The top left tile is https://maraoz.com/decentraland-maps/map/5,8,8.png and bottom right is https://maraoz.com/decentraland-maps/map/5,22,21.png  Then you can set the resolution you need in the view by dividing the real tile size by the size you want (16 seems very small for a full page map so this example uses 64).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        tileSize = [784, 783];
        extent = [0, 0, tileSize[0] * 15, tileSize[1] * 14];
        center = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
        origin = [tileSize[0] * -8, tileSize[1] * 22];
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'decentraland-images',
          units: 'pixels',
          extent: extent,
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileImage({
              url: 'https://maraoz.com/decentraland-maps/map/{z},{x},{y}.png',
              tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                extent: extent,
                origin: origin,
                tileSize: tileSize,
                resolutions: [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1],
                minZoom: 5
              }),
              projection: projection
            }),
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection,
            center: center,
            resolutions: [tileSize[0] / 64],
            zoom: 0
          })
        });
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        min-height: 100%; 
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: rgba(51,51,51,0.7);
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike! Can you explain a little bit the logic behind the `origin` and both `resolutions` parameters? My images changed and I haven't been able to adapt your code to the new 800x800 resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Origin is where the top right corner of tile z/0/0 would be if your had a tile at 0/0.  Resolution value 1 is the real size of your image.  As you only have tiles where z=5 index 5 of the array is set to 1, the other descending order values are not used but are needed to fill the array indexes 0 to 4.

Comment: Thanks @Mike! Last question: what are the values 14 and 15 in `extent = [0, 0, tileSize[0] * 15, tileSize[1] * 14];`??

Comment: nevermind Mike, I got it to work! will post the solution soon :D

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working so I'll self-post the answer here for future reference in case anyone else wants to create a zoomable map with a single set of custom images in OpenLayers:

```
        var zoom = 6;
        var side = 400
        var extent = [0, 0, side*30*2, side*30*2];
        var center = [side*30+side/2, side*30-side/2];
        var origin = [side*0, side * 60];
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'decentraland-images',
          units: 'pixels',
          extent: extent,
        });
        var resolutions = [];
        var viewResolutions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= zoom; ++i) {
          resolutions.push(Math.pow(2, zoom-i));
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
          viewResolutions.push(side/Math.pow(2, 3+i))
        }
        var map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.TileImage({
                url: 'map/{z}/{x},{y}.png',
                wrapX: false,
                tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                  extent: extent,
                  origin: origin,
                  tileSize: [side, side],
                  resolutions: resolutions,
                  minZoom: zoom
                }),
              }),
            }), 
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
              projection: projection,
              center: center,
              resolutions: viewResolutions,
              zoom: 4,
              minZoom: 2,
            })
        });
      }
```